# Unable to create a directory with os.mkdir though it doesn't exist

Tags: python, mkdir, python-os

I tried to create a directory with `os.mkdir`, but it raised `FileExistsError`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'test'
```

The file `test` does exist, but it is a regular file instead of a directory.

```
  0 -rw-r--r--  1 sparkandshine  staff       0 Jan 31 17:09 test
```

How do I create a directory `test/` in this case?

Comment: You can't simultaneously have a file and directory with the same name inside the same directory. Delete or rename one.

Comment: @Kevin, thx for pointing out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating systems do not allow files and directories with the same name. A directory is simply a special type of file.

See the following for more information:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/why-cant-i-have-a-folder-and-a-file-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a file and a directory named the same thing.
If you had the file called `test.txt` or something it would work

```
~> touch test
~> mkdir test
mkdir: test: File exists
```